# How to get bar id in react highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I form charts and a have such series format:

```
series: {
                            id  : '001',
                            name: 'name,
                            data: [],
                            color: '#fff'
                        }
```

In plotOptions I created onClick event:

```
plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    marker: {
                        states: {
                            select: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: function () {
                                console.log('!!!!!', this);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

After clock i get object in log. There is all information except id: '001'. How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You attached the click event to the point, so `this` inside the callback refer to the point object. Id is defined in series' options.

You can access it from `series.options` object:

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function() {
      console.log('!!!!!', this.series.options.id);
    }
  }
}
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/4s3ayhfy/